# How to preserve original document's systemId in XSL chain?

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I have a bunch of XSLs. One of them happens to use base-uri().

When run directly against a file, it's shows the document's systemId.
When run after another XSL, it shows that XSL's systemId.

Things I don't have control over

- XSL contents
- Order of XSLs
- Has to work with XSLT2 (saxon)

Also, I would prefer a streaming solution. This could be fixed by writing every intermediate result to disk and faking the systemId to that of the original document, but that is highly inefficient.

Here's what I've tried thus far.

```
public class BadSystemIdDemo {
  private static final SAXTransformerFactory XSLT2 =
      new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Result to = new StreamResult(System.out);

    // outputs: "file:///one.xsl"
    usingXMLFilter(to);
    System.out.println();

    // also outputs: "file:///one.xsl"
    usingTransformerHandler(to);
    System.out.println();

    // wanted: "file:///in.xml"
  }

  private static void usingTransformerHandler(Result to) throws Exception {
    TransformerHandler first = XSLT2.newTransformerHandler(Inputs.xsl1());
    TransformerHandler second = XSLT2.newTransformerHandler(Inputs.xsl2());

    first.setResult(new SAXResult(second));
    second.setResult(to);

    XSLT2.newTransformer().transform(Inputs.in(), new SAXResult(first));
  }

  private static void usingXMLFilter(Result to) throws Exception {
    XMLReader r = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
    XMLFilter first = XSLT2.newXMLFilter(Inputs.xsl1());
    XMLFilter second = XSLT2.newXMLFilter(Inputs.xsl2());

    first.setParent(r);
    second.setParent(first);

    XSLT2.newTransformer().transform(Inputs.in(second), to);
  }
}
```

Just examples, the real things are obviously more complicated.

```
public class Inputs {
  private static final String IN_SYSTEM_ID = "file:///in.xml";
  private static final String XSL1_SYSTEM_ID = "file:///one.xsl";
  private static final String XSL2_SYSTEM_ID = "file:///two.xsl";

  static Source in() {
    return new StreamSource(new StringReader("<root/>"), IN_SYSTEM_ID);
  }

  static Source in(XMLReader using) {
    return new SAXSource(using, SAXSource.sourceToInputSource(in()));
  }

  static Source xsl1() {
    String contents = ""
        + "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"2.0\""
        + "                xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">"
        + "  <xsl:template match=\"@*|node()\">"
        + "    <xsl:copy>"
        + "      <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*|node()\"/>"
        + "    </xsl:copy>"
        + "  </xsl:template>"
        + "</xsl:stylesheet>";
    return new StreamSource(new StringReader(contents), XSL1_SYSTEM_ID);
  }

  static Source xsl2() {
    String contents = ""
        + "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"2.0\""
        + "                xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">"
        + "  <xsl:template match=\"*\">"
        + "    <xsl:value-of select=\"base-uri(.)\"/>"
        + "  </xsl:template>"
        + "</xsl:stylesheet>";
    return new StreamSource(new StringReader(contents), XSL2_SYSTEM_ID);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working by overriding the XMLReader#setDocumentLocator(). This is rather hackish though and will probably break if the input document is using XInclude.

```
  private static void usingTransformerHandler(Result to) throws Exception {
    TransformerHandler first = XSLT2.newTransformerHandler(Inputs.xsl1());
    TransformerHandler second = XSLT2.newTransformerHandler(Inputs.xsl2());

    LocatorFixer fixer = new LocatorFixer();
    first.setResult(new SAXResult(fixer.wrap(second)));
    second.setResult(to);

    XSLT2.newTransformer().transform(Inputs.in(), new SAXResult(fixer.wrap(first)));
  }

  private static void usingXMLFilter(Result to) throws Exception {
    XMLReader r = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
    XMLFilter first = XSLT2.newXMLFilter(Inputs.xsl1());
    XMLFilter second = XSLT2.newXMLFilter(Inputs.xsl2());

    LocatorFixer fixer = new LocatorFixer();
    first.setParent(fixer.wrap(r));
    second.setParent(fixer.wrap(first));

    XSLT2.newTransformer().transform(Inputs.in(second), to);
  }
```

Helper

```
class LocatorFixer {
  private Locator copied;

  XMLFilterImpl wrap(XMLReader delegate) {
    return new XMLFilterImpl(delegate) {
      @Override
      public void setDocumentLocator(Locator real) {
        if (copied != null) {
          super.setDocumentLocator(copied);
        } else {
          copied = new LocatorImpl(real);
          super.setDocumentLocator(real);
        }
      }
    };
  }

  ContentHandler wrap(ContentHandler delegate) {
    XMLFilterImpl fixed = wrap((XMLReader) null);
    fixed.setContentHandler(delegate);
    return fixed;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My first idea would be to add an xml:base attribute to the tree; that will determine the result of the base-uri() function. But given the constraints you describe, perhaps that's too disruptive.

To be honest, I don't really believe the constraints. If you've got control over the Java code, then you can create a stylesheet which imports xsl2 and overrides the template that calls base-uri(), replacing it with a reference to a stylesheet parameter.

However, if you're prepared to move away from the JAXP interface to Saxon's s9api API, then it can probably be done. To set up a transformation pipeline in s9api you use one XsltTransformer as the Destination for another XsltTransformer, and by calling setBaseUri() on the second XsltTransformer you should affect the result of base-uri() called within that stylesheet.

Comment: Option 1: might make the XML schema invalid, so that's out.  
Option 2: I'm actually applying a XSL to a XML document and passing that to a 3rd party library that applies its own XSL (which does the base-uri() somewhere), and I can't change the 3rd party library, so this doesn't work either.  
Option 3: This will work.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, setBaseURI() does not exist on XsltTransformer. Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered. Perhaps you could use a DocumentBuilder as a destination of one phase of transformation (having set the base URI on the document builder) and then use the resulting document as the source of the next phase. I can't provide an example without actually writing and debugging the code for you, which is not something I have time to do.